# SQL Oracle select second max

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to retrieve the second maximum value between some dates linked to the id.
I tried this way but it keeps always giving me the highest date and not the second one:

```
SELECT id_dependent, max("date")
  FROM gest
 WHERE data NOT IN (SELECT MAX ("date") FROM gest)
GROUP BY id_dependent
```

The table is:

| id | date | id_dependent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 23-apr-2022 | C1 |
| 2. | 15-sep-2021 | C1 |
| 3. | 07-jan-2019 | C1 |
| 4. | 12-mar-2018 | C2 |
| 5. | 21-nov-2020 | C2 |
| 6. | 05-may-2019 | C2 |
| 7. | 17-feb-2021 | C3 |
| 8. | 20-nov-2020 | C3 |
| 9. | 31-dec-2017 | C3 |
| 10. | 21-oct-2018 | C4 |
| 11. | 18-feb-2023 | C4 |

Thx

Comment: Hi @rogers79: Thanks for your question!... I am changing your date column as dated as date is a function and would cause issues..

Answer (score 2):

Try this (using analytic function)

```
SELECT "date"
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                           (PARTITION BY id_dependent ORDER BY "date" DESC) AS row_n, 
              "date"
          FROM gest) 
 WHERE row_n = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select id_dependent,dated FROM(Select id_dependent,dated ,
    RANK() over(partition by id_dependent 
    order by dated desc) rn from table )
    where rn=2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want 2nd max by id_dependent

-- untested

```
select id_dependent, max(data)  from 
gest  gest_out where data not in 
      (SELECT MAX (data), id_dependent 
      FROM gest gest_in where gest_out.id_dependent = gest_in.id_dependent 
      group by id_dependent) 
       group by id_dependent
```

Comment: Your subquery is returning both `max(data)` and `id_dependent`, you only need the first and you don't need the `group by` because you're already filtering on that column with an equality condition. I prefer this answer to the others as it's trying to fix what's broken rather than saying just do something else.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DATE
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_DEPENDENT ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS NR,
DATE
FROM DUAL)
WHERE NR= 2